# Trying to implement a comparator with hysteresis

Tags: comparator, hysteresis

So here's the circuit:

[image]

I need to design the comparator with hysteresis.

So i saw this video:

[image]

I was thinking of doing the same on my circuit.

Vin will be connected to R1 and RNTC where it will form a voltage divider, Vin = R1/(R1+RNTC) * Vcc.

The RNTC is a negative coefficient thermistor where its resistance changes with temperature.

T1=20ºC and T2=21.5ºC so i would find the resistance equivalent value for those two temperatures and compute Vin20ºC and Vin21.5ºC, Vref would be the mid point of those two voltages and Vhyst would be the difference of the two (Vin21.5ºC - Vin20ºC). Then i would do follow the recipe of the second image i provided you guys with.

Do you think that will work?

Comment: How do you expect it to perform?   cycling frequency?  Thermistor latency? cooling effects with wind?  relay arcing?   Perhaps a variable speed phase controlled Triac might work better. It all depends on your expectations or "specs" and assumptions on performance.

Answer (score 2):

In general it will function. There are details. Since there is a pullup resistor I will assume an open-collector or open-drain comparator. The loading caused by the transistor in the following stage will change Vo(max) in particular so the hysteresis calculation will be incorrect.

Also, note that the hysteresis is not symmetrical about the input since the output never goes negative, so the ideal reference voltage is not centered on the voltages for the high and low temperatures.

I suggest swapping (+) and (-) inputs, feeding the positive feedback to the reference rather than the sensor. Then you can use a PNP transistor so the output voltage swings from about 50-100mV to +12.

I encourage you to calculate the resistor dividers from first principles. You will have two dividers, one with two resistors and the second with three.

Once you have the Vo(max), Vo(min) you will end up with two equations in two unknowns which you can solve numerically or the hard way. The circuit should then work as predicted with no adjustments or fiddling required.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHcXt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Check that the base voltage of the transistor is not too low when it is supposed to be off (with the values I suggest it will be okay, less than 100mV Vbe).

Answer (score 0):

Non-inverting Schmitt Trigger design procedure.

[image: Schmitt Trigger design]